# How to parallelize database query using ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, threadpool

I'm bugfixing someone else's code where it takes ages to return the complete dataset in the following code:

```
DataTable dt = someLib.GetDataTable("EXEC [dbo].[CMS_Content_GetAllContents]");

// Copy the DataTable data to list.
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    ContentInfo aContentDetail = new ContentInfo(
            (int)dr["ID"],
            (string)dr["ContentName"],
            getCategories((int)dr["ID"]),
            null,
            (string)dr["Publisher"],
            (string)dr["Price"],
            false);

    contentInfoList.Add(aContentDetail); ;
}

private string getCategories(int ContentID)
{
    String categories = String.Empty;
    String query = String.Format("EXEC [dbo].[CMS_Content_GetContentCategories] @ID = {0}", ContentID);

    DataTable dt = clsGlobal.GetDataTable(query);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        categories = String.Concat((string)dr["ShortDescription"] + ", ");                
    }

    if (categories.EndsWith(", "))
        categories = categories.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', ' ' });

    return categories;
}
```

It is pathetic as there are over 1,000 rows for the DataTable dt and I cannot deal with it from the stored procedure level!

I'm just wondering if I can bundle the call `getCategories(int)` into `Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem()` such that it can go parallel but dunno how to return the string back to the caller?

Or, is it a bad idea to use Threadpool because I heard that the Threadpool's workers threads are not designed for long running queries such as DB calls as the IOCompletion ports thread may not return in time hence workers are likely to get blocked because of that?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's a mess I'm dealing with, rite?

Comment: I'm not posting an answer since I'm not sure, but I think doing this using threads would be a bad idea. Instead if I was faced with this I'd start by profiling to find just where the bottleneck is (there are several things that could be costly in what you posted) and then if it is DB I'd look at turning the GetCategories call into a single call with an array of the ids - doing to category association in code would probably be lots faster rather then multiple db calls in a for loop.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to perform other tasks while waiting for the categories to be returned? If not, please elaborate.

Comment: Hi Gabe, the code is getting a table of IDs and then for each IDs fetch the categories, I know it's a mess, think I'll touch down to the DB and get my hands dirty there.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that threading isn't the answer in this case (on or off the threadpool).  Fixing the 1000 calls to the database is.  You might optimize the speed of your response for a small number of users, but the response time would still be pretty excruciating, and your app is going to fall over at a very low load.

I don't know how much control you have over the database, so here are some ideas that span a few layers:

1. Pull the categories with the content.  You can either create a func to string delimit them, or use a proc that returns multiple datasets in one call.
2. Load all the categories up at once, and put the data together in memory
3. Change your UI so that you aren't using 1000 CMS items at once.  Paging or something.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it took over 10 minutes for the UI thread to get back to response.

Think I'll take #2 from your answers above and get hacking with a new store proc.  Just want to get it over and done with.   Many thanks.

Time to find a new job perhaps! :-)

Comment: One where they'll give you fritos. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Though, the question has been answer. But this is just so it might help.

You can "move" your code inside a worker thread and let it run. You can also create add an event and as soon as the thread finishes the work, it would let you know. This way you can continue(or move the progress bar to the end, if you have any?) with the rest of your work.

1. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) is how you work with threads.
2. This is [what I love](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), to date.

As a side note, I believe this can be done in the SP(if you can share the query); therefore I would create an SP that fetches the content detail, and for each ContentDetailID, I would prepare a comma separated list of categories and then return with my result.

So, your call will just be:

```
DataTable dt = someLib.GetDataTable("EXEC [dbo].[CMS_Content_GetAllContents_Ex]");//Note the _EX in the sp name (0:
```